# python: how to find index in dict containing list of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am reading a file (with three columns) and then populating a dict that has three keys: `app`, `version`, and `domains`.

Sample contents of the file are:

```
app            version    domain
---            ---        ---
com.easytaxi   1.1        google.com
com.easytaxi   1.1        facebook.com
com.easytaxi   1.1        google.com
com.easytaxi   1.2        google.com
com.airbnb     1.1        facebook.com
com.airbnb     1.1        facebook.com
```

I would like to store the contents of the file in the dict such that I store a list of unique domains for each app, version pair. The output dictionary should contain the following items:

```
dict_data = {'app':['com.easytaxi','com.easytaxi','com.airbnb'],
            'version':[1.1,1.2,1.1],
            'domains':[['google.com','facebook.com'],['google.com'],['facebook.com']]}
```

I have tried the following so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(u'''app,version,domain
com.easytaxi,1.1,google.com
com.easytaxi,1.1,facebook.com
com.easytaxi,1.1,google.com
com.easytaxi,1.2,google.com
com.airbnb,1.1,facebook.com
com.airbnb,1.1,facebook.com''')

df = pd.read_csv(data)
dict_data = {'app':[],'version':[],'domains':[[]]}

for index,row in df.iterrows():  # iterating each row of df
    # need to fix this
    if row['app'] in dict_data['app'] & row['version'] in dict_data['version']:
        if row['domain'] not in dict_data['domains']:
            # then append row['domain'] to dict_data['domains'] on the correct index
```

Comment: df.to_dict('list')?

Comment: @anky_91 no that doesn't do what op asked

Comment: @anky_91 I need to discard duplicate values for `app`, `domain`, and `version`, and append different domain value to the list (within the list) for same `app` and `domain`. The required output is given in the question.

Comment: @d_kennetz sorry, didnt test, typed in mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(u'''app,version,domain
com.easytaxi,1.1,google.com
com.easytaxi,1.1,facebook.com
com.easytaxi,1.1,google.com
com.easytaxi,1.2,google.com
com.airbnb,1.1,facebook.com
com.airbnb,1.1,facebook.com''')

df = pd.read_csv(data)

df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.groupby(["app", "version"]).agg(list).reset_index().sort_values(
    "app", ascending=False
).to_dict("list")
```

This'll give you

```
{'app': ['com.easytaxi', 'com.easytaxi', 'com.airbnb'],
 'version': [1.1, 1.2, 1.1],
 'domain': [['google.com', 'facebook.com'], ['google.com'], ['facebook.com']]}
```

Comment: I get a ValueError: Function does not reduce

Comment: @SaadH  Have made an edit, can you try this? If it still doesn't work, what version of pandas do you have?

Comment: 0.20.3, 
I tried the same code on a different system running pandas 0.24.2 and I get the `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: Can you try with `0.25.3`? I just copy and pasted the code above and it worked :)